# getting error ORA-00907 while creating a table in sql developer

Tags: sql, oracle

i am fresh to sql developer. i am not sure about the rules. when i practiced following teacher's example to create a small library database, i have that error to every table with foreign key. i check the example and i am sure i have not miss a parenthesis. i am so confused. please help!

```
create table Publisher
(Pname VARCHAR(25)  not null ,
 Address varchar(25) not null,
 Phone char(10),
 PRIMARY KEY (Pname));

create table Book
(Book_id int not null,
 Title varchar(20),
 Publisher_name varchar(25) ,
 primary KEY (Book_id),
    foreign key (Publisher_name) references Publisher(Pname)
      ON DELETE CASCADE   ON UPDATE CASCADE);
```

error report shows that between first cascade and second on "missing right parenthesis". but i don't think so. similar question happens to all other similar construct. my sql developer is the latest version for mac.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with the `ON UPDATE CASCADE` part?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson  Define triggered actions that will be attached to each foreign key constraint follow the example in the book...

Comment: Oracle does not support `ON UPDATE CASCADE`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thank you. i need to talk to my teacher, asking her to check her slide.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're trying to ensure that the `Book` records are updated whenever you change the `Pname` column in the `Publisher` table, but Oracle has no `on update cascade`.

See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/clauses002.htm#CJAIHHGC) for the syntax diagram of the `references` clause.

To change primary keys in Oracle, you have a few options:

- [Defer the constraint](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10003.htm) (foreign key) check until commit, then update both parent and child within the transaction.
- Create a *new* parent with the updated details then go change all the children, then delete the original parent. All in a transaction of course.
- Stop using mutable data as a key. It took a long time for DBAs to convince me that artificial (surrogate) keys should be used rather than true data, but this was the use case that finally won me over. Using an artificial key (that never has to change) means this problem disappears totally.

Comment: i just follow the example given by my teacher... i have no idea about that.  what can i do to achieve that goal in oracle.

Comment: @G_cy: find out what variant of DBMS is being used by your teacher, then use that one. What were you thinking anyway, using a DBMS that can't tell the difference between an empty string and a NULL? Although, given I no longer work for Big Blue, maybe I can stop dissing Oracle now :-)

Comment: thank you dude. i really have no idea about this application. i just start to learn about it and follow the example in slide. this error makes crazy all the night. i need to talk with my teacher.